# Latex Template for this type of Resume

Tags: cv

I am searching endlessly for the Latex template for this type of resume. If anyone has the link then it would be immensely helpful! Thanks!

[image: latexCV]
<sub>(source: [leahrn.org](http://leahrn.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/latex-resume-template-59tkpgp8.png))</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The full template you posted itself is here:

http://links.tedpavlic.com/tex/tpavlic_cv_faculty.tex

You can compile directly with pdflatex.

And Ted's Home Page is also here with lots of stuff:

http://www.tedpavlic.com/post_resume_cv_latex_example.php

Comment: awesome!! Thanks a lot!! But the fonts dont match. Which font is in use in this pic and how to manually change it? :)

Comment: @KoustuvSinha  The default Computer Modern font is used in the posted image. Whereas in the link I posted, it is Times Roman.

Comment: You're most welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's a variation of this template? [Medium length graduate CV](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/medium-length-graduate-cv) (http://www.latextemplates.com/template/medium-length-graduate-cv) - the contact information is set as two-column.

Comment: maybe, but fonts dont match, alignments are not the same. would be helpful to find the exact template, although I am scouring the net but unable to find it :(